# Получить список пользователей в django

Tags: python, django

Надо чтоб на сайте отображалось список пользователей

вот мои коды

Шаблон

```
{% block content %}

{% for users in users_list %}
<p>
    {{ users.user }}
</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', kabinet, name='kabinet'),
path('update/', kabinetedit, name='kabinetedit'),
path('delete/', kabimgdel, name='kabimgdel'),
path('kablist/', kablist, name='kablist')]
```

views.py

```
def kablist(request):
    users_list = UserProfile.objects.all()

    context = {
            "title": "ListUser",
        }
    return render(request, 'accounts/kablist.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='imageusers', verbose_name='Изображение')
    infouser = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=5)
```

Comment: Вы не передали `users_list` в шаблон, он естественно работать не будет

Comment: Как не передавал а for users in users_list ?

Comment: Эта строчка не передаёт, а использует переданное значение. А вы его не передали, поэтому эта строчка просто ничего не делает. В ответе написали как правильно передать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def kablist(request):
    users_list = UserProfile.objects.all()

    context = {
            "title": "ListUser",
            "users_list": users_list,
        }
    return render(request, 'accounts/kablist.html', context)
```

Comment: Ахх да как забыл :)

Comment: Получилось все огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за решение. Я не стал создавать новую модель и сделал так:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def userslist(request):
    users_list = get_user_model().objects.all()
    template_name = 'users/users-list.html'
    context = {
        "title": "зарегистрированные пользователи",
        "users_list": users_list,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name=template_name, context=context)
```